# Use the RegDeleteKeyValue API as an Admin

Tags: windows, registry, key-value

I am using the `RegDeleteKeyValue`() to delete a registry key value from my C++ code. However, upon execution I get a `0x80070005` (Access denied error). How do I execute the function as an admin?

Comment: You don't, you execute the entire program as an admin, by including a manifest with requestedExecutionLevel set to requireAdministrator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed a manifest file at compile time in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084585/how-to-embed-a-manifest-file-at-compile-time-in-visual-studio-2010)