# how to set "run as admin" registry key, on Windows 8.1, using Inno Setup

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, inno-setup

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978917/how-to-set-run-as-administrator-on-a-file-using-innosetup) how to add a run-as-admin registry key to a program installed  by an installer made with Innno-Setup, but it only worked on Windows 7. **I need it to work on Windows 8.1**, both 32- and 64-bit.

(The program im installing is a 32-bit .exe. The Installer.exe is also 32-bit AFAIK)

Can someone show me the right registry instruction for windows 8.1? and also **how to check if its a windows 7 or 8** machine before executing the registry instruction? Thanks.

Comment: That was a different case when the OP wanted to create a shortcut that will run a foreign application elevated. If your application is always supposed to run elevated, use the application manifest. As a bonus, here are [`the functions`](http://pastebin.com/R9H6fYtF) to determine those Windows versions, but I believe you won't need them. In any case, I'm not considering that registry solution to be a good way.

Comment: Well I followed that solution and it worked just fine on Windows 7. I'd love to try the manifest way too, but could you tell me where that is? My game is made in MonoGame using Visual Studio 2010 and there's nothing in the solution tree named 'manifest'.

Comment: [`Try this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4084620/960757) (that is the generic way for embedding application manifests into the VS projects; just please note, that I know nothing about MonoGame, so don't forget to make backups ;)

Comment: Thanks, the manifest solution worked perfectly on Win 7 and Win 8.1.